# Can't find specific element in LinkedListNode

Tags: c#

Let's start from the beginning. I have string:

```
LOAD  B
STORE $2
LOAD  A
MPY   =5.01E+10
ADD   $2
```

What looks in code this way:

```
string code = "LOAD  B\r\nSTORE $2\r\nLOAD  A\r\nMPY   =5.01E+10\r\nADD   $2\r\n";
```

And transform it into LinkedListNode this way:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs =
                code.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x[0], x[1]));

            var data = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(pairs);
```

Element of this list is KeyValuePair containing left and right parts of every line of string. Now is main part. I have to find in this list sequence `"LOAD a => STORE b"` where `a` and `b` can be any string. After this i have to find in next part of my list all elements with `key == b` (in my example `b = "$2"`) and replace `b` to `a` so here would be:

```
LOAD  B
STORE B //changed
LOAD  A
MPY   =5.01E+10
ADD   B //changed
```

So, here is my code to this:

```
string a;
string b;
for(LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<string, string>> it = data.First; it != null; it = it.Next) { 
    if(it.Next != null) {
        if ((it.Value.Key == "LOAD") &&
            (it.Next.Value.Key == "STORE")) {

            a = it.Value.Value;
            b = it.Next.Value.Value;

            for(LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<string, string>> 
                current = it; current != null; 
                current = current.Next) {

                //remove found element and replace it
                if (current.Value.Value == b) { 
                    data.AddAfter(current, new KeyValuePair<string, string> (current.Value.Key, a));
                    data.Remove(current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After i run it i get this:

```
LOAD  B
STORE B //changed
LOAD  A
MPY   =5.01E+10
ADD   $2 //still the same
```

I tryed to debug it and figured out, that `if (current.Value.Value == b)` don't actually match `ADD   $2` in some reason. What can be wrong?

This is how you can see what is in list:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in data) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} - Value: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution:

```
if (current.Value.Value == b) { 
    current.Value = new KeyValuePair<string, string> (current.Value.Key, a);
}
```

If you need to replace value of list element you just need:

```
LinkedListNode.Value = new value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason your code is broken, is that when you remove `current` from the linked list in your inner loop, the values for `Next` and `Previous` for the `LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` get set to null. Hence your iteration in the inner loop terminates as soon as you make any replacement in the list. Check those values in your debugger immediately after `data.Remove(current)` to see what I mean.

I'd use slightly different patterns in trying to modify the data as you describe. When I had a quick go at hacking up a solution in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), I came up with this:

```
var newData = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
Nullable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> previousNode = null;
string valueToFind = "$2";
string valueToReplace = null;
foreach(var currentNode in data)
{
    if(previousNode != null)
    {
        if(previousNode.Value.Key == "LOAD" && currentNode.Key == "STORE")
        {
            valueToReplace = previousNode.Value.Value;
        }
    }

    if(valueToReplace != null && currentNode.Value == valueToFind)
    {
        var newValue = new KeyValuePair<string,string>(currentNode.Key, valueToReplace);
        newData.AddLast(newValue);
    }
    else
    {
        newData.AddLast(currentNode);
    }

    previousNode = currentNode;
}
```

Rather than modifying the existing list in place, I'm creating a copy. I find it easier to read code where it's not modifying the data structure that's being iterated over. Plus, I think this gets rid of your bug.

So I'm starting off with a null value for "what was the previous node in the list", and iterating through the entire list with a `foreach()`. If there is a previous node to look at, then the code checks to see if it was "LOAD" and the current node is "STORE". If so, it takes a copy of the parameter for the "LOAD" operation as the "value to replace".

Then, if we have a value to replace and the current node's `Value` is equal to the value we need to find ("$2" in your example) the code creates a new list node with the replacement made. Otherwise it just inserts the current node as-is into the new list.

That gives the following output for me:

[image: My results]

Which I think is what you were after?

Comment: But in fact i do this procedure in loop. And entering string can have more than one "LOAD a => STORE b"

Comment: Also, earlier in the same code i removed lots of elements of list by loop and all works fine. And i succesfully write right cutted list in a file. So Remove must save connections.

Comment: Anyway interesting idea.